# Oracle explicit lock timeout

Tags: oracle11g

I have a situation where multiple nodes of a webapp can attempt to perform some operation on a n Oracle table. The solution we came up with was to get an explicit lock (on some separate lock object or the table itself(open to feedback on this)) and that way only one node would attempt to perform that operation. The only problem with this idea is the scenario where the node that acquires the lock crashes. So my question has to do with whether Oracle allows you to specify the lock timeout at the time you acquire it (don't want this to be specified globally)

Thanks.

P.S. This is with Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a statement level timeout for DML commands (insert,select for update,delete,merge).  For DDL statements you can specify at a session level.  There is also a "skip locks" clause where you can allow the statement to skip only the rows that have been already locked.